# Is there anoter way than Barracuda to Run Onnx models in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, onnx

I am trying to get a onnx model running on the HoloLens using Unity. As I found out I think the way to go would be using Barracuda to import the model. But I am facing the Problem that only 4 Dimensional Tensors are supported and i am using a 5 Dimensional input.

So here the question: Is there another way to use a onnx model in Unity than Barracuda? In Python you can just start the ONNX Runtime and it's done - so is there a similar way to do so in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I did not do this directly, but I see that the ONNX runtime is available as a .NET Standard NuGet package

- GPU: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime.gpu)
- CPU: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime

So I believe you can use that in Unity.